# How to set “draw line inside polygon” using Python?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

In the QGIS properties of a layer I want to activate "draw line only inside polygon" for a specific layer, but using Python. I don't want to use the GUI for it.

Can this be done?

I set the line width with the following code:

```
props['line_width'] = '1.0'
lineLayer = QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry.instance().symbolLayerMetadata("SimpleLine").createSymbolLayer(props)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to check the "draw line only inside polygon" checkbox?

Please see attached image.
[image: Qgis layer properties]

Comment: This worked `props['draw_inside_polygon'] = '1'`.

Comment: You should consider posting your comment as an **answer** and then accepting it (which can only be done 2 days after first posting the question) =)

Answer (score 1):

To set "Draw line only inside polygon" using python I used

```
props['draw_inside_polygon'] = '1'
```